# How can I visualize the sample space of a complicated random experiment?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

A sample space $\Omega$ of a random experiment is the set of all possible outcomes $\omega$. When dealing with random variables (which, formally, is a map from $\Omega \mapsto R$), we usually operate at a higher level. But I have a particular application in which I would be interested to explore the underlying sample space.

Let's look at the typical experiment of hashing $n$ keys from a set $K$ to $m$ bins, using a hash function $h: K \mapsto \{0,1,\dots,m-1\}$. For completion, we have the following property (not very important)

$$
\forall \; \text{keys } i,j, i \ne j, \; Pr\{h(i)=h(j)\} = \frac{1}{m}
$$

Furthermore, define the event $A_{ij} = \text{keys } i,j \text{ fall in the same bin}$. This event $A$ must be some subset of the sample space, but I cannot quite see how $\Omega$ is defined for this experiment.

One possibility of an outcome $\omega$ is the set of all pairs of the form $( \langle i,j\rangle, True)$, or $False$ if $i,j$ do not collide.

Another possibility is an $n$-tuple $\langle b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n\rangle$, where the $i^{th}$ term is the bin that key $i$ falls in to. There seems to be many other possibilities.

But we can also define indicator variables, find the expected number of collisions, and many other computations, all of which seem to be independent of how we modeled the sample space.

Is there a certain way in which we view the outcomes? I hope the confusion is clear.

Comment: The most convenient sample space is your set of $n$-tuples.

Comment: Thanks for the comment; how can we make decisions about what is 'most convenient'?

Comment: On this sample space, I assume the model will be that all assignments are equally likely. "Equally likely" is a desirable property.